# Spring Data JPA repository methods overloading

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, spring-data-jpa

For example, I have a book JpaRepository. Book has a field called `Name`, the book repository has a method `findOneByName` (as the jpa repository method naming convention). But I need two different versions of `findOneByName` to use in  different use cases. One version is ***lock annotated***, the other is ***lock-free***. Like this:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<BookDAO, Long> {

   @Lock(LockModeType.READ)
   BookDAO findOneByName( String name );

   BookDAO findOneByName( String name );
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this in Spring? If so, how to distinguish the two methods when calling them. If not, is there another way to do it while still using the Spring JPA repository interfaces (like findOneBy***).

Comment: I would just not use Query methods for one of them. I would create a new method for the @Lock one and call it something like `findOneByNameWithLock(name)`. Then use the @Query annotation and specify the query for it.

Comment: No, not like this (and the has nothing to do with Spring but how Java works).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. Do you have some constructive suggestions regarding this use case? How to do it in another way?

Comment: See the comment from @LucasP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it can be done your way. But i would create different methods

```
 public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<BookDAO, Long> {

   @Lock(LockModeType.READ)
   @Query("select b from Book b where b.name = :name")
   BookDAO findOneByNameForRead( String name );

   BookDAO findOneByName( String name );

}
```

or you can create methods in your service layer instead of using spring jparepository to handle locking. and use it across where it is needed to be updated, and all read methods marked as @Transactional(readOnly = true)

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
...

public  Book findOneBookForUpdate(String id) {

    Book book = em.find(Book.class, id);
    if (book != null) {
        em.lock(book, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    }

    return book;
}
```

Comment: It will not work. The second method calls the first one which is equivalent to a direct call to the first method.

Comment: There is a chance that between em.find() and em.lock() another transaction obtains a lock on the entity. If this happens, em.lock may fail, subject to transaction isolation level.

Answer (score 5):

According to [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) we can name query methods with these prefixes: `find…By`, `read…By`, `query…By`, `count…By`, and `get…By`.

So methods `BookDAO findByName(String name)` and `BookDAO getByName(String name)` will do the same thing.